# Can access to play secret allow server compromise/cryptocurrency theft?

Tags: scala, security, playframework, app-secret

Our play secret was leaked in source version control system. Few days later our server was compromised and cryptocurrency stolen. Could it be correlated?

What exactly can be done using play secret?

Suppose attacker does not have latest source but an older  version and our servers secret, can he do much?
What exactly?

Answer (score 2):

In regards to what one can do with a play secret. The [answer is in the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ApplicationSecret)

> Anyone that can get access to the secret will be able to generate any session they please, effectively allowing them to log in to your system as any user they please. Hence it is strongly recommended that you do not check your application secret into source control. Rather, it should be configured on your production server. This means that it is considered bad practice to put the production application secret in application.conf.

Given that one can get a session and possibly log into your system that way, I would say that it's probably likely that your secret being stolen and then something in your system being stolen a bit afterward is related. That said, the only way you can tell is by auditing your system's logs to try to figure stuff out. Which I don't think anyone but you can do. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your data has been altered because one can possibly logon to your system because he can generate sessions with access to your play secret (Refer to answer above) you can try checking your logs(which only noob will keep logs.

Try reading [this](https://tech.toomakesense.com/2019/03/details-cryptocurrency-online.html) for more insights just in case of next time,  be careful